# Does Tomb Reaver work with Wirlwind?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

Does the "10% Reanimate As: Returned" of ["Tomb Reaver"](https://diablo2.io/uniques/tomb-reaver-t997.html) work together with [Wirlwind](https://diablo2.io/skills/whirlwind-t4197.html). I know that "On Attack", "On Striking" or "When You Kill an Enemy" does not work with Wirlwind. But does the Reanimate of Tomb Reaver belong to the same kind of attribute or is it something special, which works with Wirlwind?